# Coming up with MySQL query on multiple tables

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-workbench

I need to come up with a query which I am finding to be a bit complex.

This is my database structure:

[image]

The user will add/enter filters, and depending on the filters, there will be displayed correspondent Collections of magazines and newspapers.

The possible filters are:

- Magazine/Newspaper name
- fromDate
- toDate
- Select if the results are only from Magazine or Newspaper or both
- If the Collection has been analysed or not

Well, suposing that the user has entered a name, both dates, both magazine and newspaper and only collections that have been analysed, how would the query look like? I would like to display the collectionDate, newspaper/magazine name, from and to dates. 
I have been trying to figure out the query but I am struggling a bit.

Does anyone have suggestions? Hope that everything is clear :)

Thanks!

Comment: Have you got a piece of code of what you have tried to do ?

Comment: from the picture it's not clear to me how the IDs correlate between the target table and the others; I take it target.type will be either 'collection','magazine', or 'newspaper', then is ssnID the corresponding table's ID?

Comment: @Joe T, I tried to highlight the IDs so it would be more clear. Magazine and newspaper are subtypes of target (sorry, I am not exactly sure how to represent this on MySQL Workbench). So the targetID would be either a newspaper ID or a magazine ID (the PKs). the ssnID is correspondent to newspaperID or magazineID, but they aren't being used for this query. Collections is not a subtype of Target, but the table Collection has the targetID as a foreign key, to identify which is the target related to a specific collection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  SELECT  m.name as mag_name,
          n.name as news_paper_name,
          c.fromDate,
          c.toDate
  FROM   Collections AS C

         INNER JOIN Target AS T ON
         C.TargetID = T.TargetID

         INNER JOIN Magazine AS M ON
         T.TargetID = M.id

         INNER JOIN Newspaper AS N ON
         T.TargerID = N.id

         INNER JOIN Analysis AS A ON
         C.CollectionID = A.CollectionID
```

This should work from a joins perspective. I am assuming that when something is anaylzed that there is a record under Analysis and not one when it has been anaylzed. Just add a where clause and whatever information you want to filter by.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it really helped me to remember somethings and clarified others.

Comment: It only has one problem. When I put both m.name and n.name it gives me Empty set. But when I do each one separately it works. Do you have any ideas on how to solve this?